# Weird jQuery show() issue - What am I not seeing?

Tags: jquery

I have a DIV that contains an image with a hotspot. It is set to hidden by default.

I have a function I call to show it.

In the function, this works:

```
$('#adChart').css("visibility", "visible");
```

But this does NOT work:

```
$('#adChart').show();
```

This does not work, either:

```
$('#adChart').fadeIn(1000);
```

(And what I really want to do is fade and slide in from the left. But I can't even get a simple show() to work at this point.)

Wrapping with Document-ready doesn't help, either. And I don't believe I need to wrap every function definition in the code with document-ready, do I? There could hundreds.

Suggestions?

Comment: Can you put together a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demonstrating the issue?

Comment: It could be a z-index issue.  Can you show us your HTML and jQuery with all of the elements that are in play for this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.show()` method doesn't affect the `visibility`. It modifies the `display` property, same thing for `fadeIn()`. That's why it doesn't work.

`.show()` is a shorcut for: `css("display", "");`

So you should use `display` CSS property instead of `visibility` if you want to use `.show()` and `fadeIn()`.

Comment: +1 because this is the right answer. However looking at the jquery source I think it is actually a shortcut for css("display","") or css("display",<saved-original-value>) depending on whether you had original set the css style to something besides the default and called hide() to hide it.

Comment: Yes. I now find that if I use 'hide()' on the DIV first (inside an Init function when the page loads), then fadeIn(1000) and show() both work. I guess hide() sets the 'display' css property, and then the other Jquery functions can use that property correctly. Not sure how I would ever have found this quickly without you guys on StackOverflow.

Comment: Keep in mind that, from a design standpoint, these are two different things.  Toggling the `visibility` property keeps the element within the content flow at all times, whereas toggling `display` (or `show()` & `hide()`) takes the element in/out of the content flow.  In other words, the surrounding content could move around when using the latter method.

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
$('#adChart').css({"visibility": "visible","display":"block","opacity":1});
```